# What is the "HealthCheck collector HostedService threw an error: Value cannot be null." mean?

Tags: .net, .net-core, health-check

Obviously something cannot be null - but I can't figure it out. I have a windows service that is self-hosted and has an endpoint that returns a `HealthCheckResult`. I then have a .Net Core Web Application that uses `HealthChecks-UI`. However, when I start both of the applications up, the healthcheck-ui says my service is in a bad status, but at the same time I can hit the url on my windows service and get a healthy status.

When I look at the output I get -

> Sending HTTP request GET {url}
>
> Received HTTP response - OK
>
> HealthCheck collector HostedService threw an error: Value cannot be
> null. (Parameter 'source')

To me, I'm getting a good 200 response, but something is failing. Ideally, I'd use the `HealthChecks` library in my app that I want to monitor, but I can't because it's a windows service. That's why I chose to implement my own and just expose a restful, self-hosted endpoint. I'm using versions 3.1 of `HealthChecks-UI`.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddHealthChecksUI()
            .AddInMemoryStorage();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting()
       .UseEndpoints(config => 
       {
           config.MapHealthChecksUI();
       });
}
```

**AppSettings.json**

```
{
   "HealthChecks-UI": {
      "HealthChecks": [
         {
            "Name", "Windows Service", "Uri": "{myRestfulEndpoint}"
         }
      ],
      "Webhooks": []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using AspNetCore.Diagnostics, check [this github issue](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/126) (particularly [this comment](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/126#issuecomment-507054841)). It looks like you are having the same issue listed (it wasn't able to find the configuration file without setting `HostDefaults.ContentRootKey` in the **WebHostBuilder**).

Comment: Interesting. That did make a difference, but now instead of getting the ```Value cannot be null``` error, I get a ```Object not set to an instance``` error.